# iOS - Using the same vanishing point for multiple elements when using CATransform3d

Tags: ios, 3d, rotation, catransform3d, vanishing-point

I'm trying to rotate multiple elements using CATransform3d, the problem is that each one is assigned an individual vanishing point. Since they are dynamic elements I cannot use an image to simulate all of them moving together. And I know no way to move them as a group.

Here is an image that clearly shows the issue and the expected outcome. [Visual Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAUKS.jpg)

Already tried every solution I could find and nothing is working for me.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you can't put all of them into one view, and then just use the CATransform3d on the containing view?  I've done this before with exactly the result you are looking for.  Just a simple add them all as subviews of a view and then perform your CATransform3D on the view.

Comment: the problem is that they are scrollable since they are cells of UITableView and we need the vanishing point to be always at the center of the screen, not at the center of the table view

Comment: So put the CATransform3D on the view that is holding the UITableView